# problem with my Lenovo G580 laptop

Tags: wireless, networking, lenovo

I have purchased Lenovo G580,on 26th January 2013.  I installed Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04LTS (32bit), but in Ubuntu it was not detecting the network connection. Because of this  I wanted to install Ubuntu 12.10 LTS (64bit).  This time it is not asking for the booting options, directly booting to Windows. I consulted a friend and we tried it for three times, and by this time the hard disk was crashed.  I contacted the Lenovo service center people they changed the hard disk and tried the same installation procedure, it was also a failure. Finally they installed only Windows 7 gave back it to me.

So my request you to advise me that what I have to do to solve this problem, I dont know whether it is the problem with the laptop (Lenovo G580) or anything else. Please give me some solutions.

sumesh

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with my G580 i installed the win 7 and then tried to install the ubuntu. it used to swipe all the space and partition and then install itself.

now what i did was.

1. i installed ubuntu on the entire hd.
2. then using Gparted from live CD i created a ntfs patrition and installed windows on it.
3. now system will boot only in the windows because windows usually override master boot record.
4. now what you have to do is to repair the grub and add an entry for window 7 in it.

here this link will possibly help you.
http://www.faqforge.com/linux/restore-grub-bootloader-after-windows-installation-on-multi-boot-system/

now after going through above link you should be able to boot into  grub now all you need to do is to add an entry for windows in grub which can be easily done by booting into the linux and doing a few simple tasks.
for that do some googling yourself.

and let me warn you my friend  that while on lenovo g580 you wont be able to switch your wireless and bluetooth on/off using Fn+F5 there is some trouble in it. you'll have to boot into windows turn on the wireless and bluetooth and then boot back into linux to use is in it.

well! 
i think you'll find it helpful.